# Action Script 3, Graph API - Load Facebook avatar, then use JPGEncoder to save image

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

im trying to load my facebook display image and then save it through as3 using JPGEncoder.

Right now im getting the image url and through a Loader, adding the image to a movie clip called foto1. This is working fine:

```
var image:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://graph.facebook.com/" + response[0].id + "/picture?type=large");
imageLoader.load(
foto1.addChild(imageLoader);
```

The problem is when i try this:

```
var myImage:Bitmap;
var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData (foto1.width, foto1.height);
jpgSource.draw(foto1);

var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(n);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);

var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

//Make sure to use the correct path to jpg_encoder_download.php
var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("http://www.thewebchi.mp/pruebas_graph/download.php?name=" + fileName + ".jpg");
jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_blank");
```

If i try the jpg process on movie clip 'foto1' without loading the external image, it works fine.
When i load the image to 'foto1' the jpg process doesnt respond.
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: looks to me like you are sending your jpgstream to a download page. It should be sent to an upload page. You didn't post the source code for download.php so there is no way of knowing whats going on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it necessary to use navigateToURL (opening in the browser window)?  If not, I would suggest using the URLLoader, `loader.load(jpgURLRequest)`.  Also, using this approach you can listen for `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` on the loader (and other events) that may give you some hints on what is wrong.